# How to handle empty or null expressions while assigning as JS variable?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, el

I am using EL expressions in my javascript code as shown below:

```
cur_step = #{obj1.step};
```

This works fine when there actually is a value inside obj1.step. However, if there is no value or is null, this is how the javascript is rendered in the browser:

```
cur_step = ;
```

This results in javascript error preventing my javascript from executing at all.

How do I fix this problem?

The obj1 object is a java bean populated on the server. FYI, I use JSF2.1 with jboss-el-2.0.jar as my EL implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a null check in your expression:

```
#{empty obj1.step ? 'something else' : obj1.step}
```

The empty keyword covers null and empty strings.

Comment: Thanks!. I coded it as #{obj1.step == undefined ? 'something else' : obj1.step}

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary array:

```
cur_step = [#{obj1.step}][0];
```